# Images appear black after upload

Tags: php, jquery, codeigniter, upload, plupload

We have two php (code igniter 3) system, the first one is with Plupload Plugin (2.3.6) + mOxie (1.5.7), and the other is only php for the upload image.

The first server is sending the images for the second with post method, but the images are going black, only black, with +/- 11033 bytes.

I did any tests with the images and upload code (gd2, imagemagick, codeigniter only, etc), but nothing, until I get to the point that I realized that the plupload (first server) is sending them this way (black integer).

plupload code

```
    $("#uploader").pluploadQueue({

        // General settings
        runtimes : 'html5,flash,gears,html4',
        url : '<?php echo $urlEnvio."galerias/".$idGaleria."/0/".$idCliente; ?>', 
        max_file_size : '100mb',
        max_file_count: 3000,
        max_retries: 3,
        chunk_size : '50mb',
        browse_button : 'uploader_browse',
        dragdrop: false,
        drop_element : 'uploader_browse',
        views: {
            list: true,
            thumbs: false, // Show thumbs
            active: 'list'
        },
        rename: true,
        multiple_queues : true,
        unique_names : false,
        multipart_params : true,
        resize : {
            width : <?php echo $largura; ?> , 
            height : <?php echo $altura; ?>, 
            quality : <?php echo $qualidade; ?> ,
            crop: false
        },
        sortable: false,
        // Specify what files to browse for
        filters : [
            { title : "Image files", extensions : "jpg,jpeg,JPG", max_file_size: "100mb" }
        ],
        // Flash settings
        flash_swf_url : '/arquivos/plupload2/Moxie.swf',
        // Silverlight settings
        silverlight_xap_url : '/arquivos/plupload2/Moxie.xap',

        init : {
```

Comment: current version of plupload: 2.3.6, maybe upgrade helps. Anyway this is a client side script, so if you get black image, it's because something with the plugin/javascript/jquery code went wrong. Also 2 servers? can you explain better what you mean with "first server is sending the images for the second"? This question is quite unclear.

Comment: Oh, sorry! 1.5.7 is the moxie, the plupload is 2.3.6. There are a lot of photos per second, and for better admin, there is a server for the client panel and a server that manages (resize, imagemagick, etc) the upload.